# getElementById problem in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this simple line

```
alert(window.parent.frames[0].document.getElementById('textToSearch').value);
```

I have 2 frames, first with a text field with id 'textToSearch'
I want to get the value of the text field in the second frame
The line above is on the html file from second frame
I get this error only in Google Chrome, in IE or FF works fine.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both frames on the same domain?

Comment: yes, both frames are included into a index page

Comment: what does 'alert(window.parent.frames.length)' and 'alert(window.parent.frames[0].toString())' give you?

Comment: for first alert returns me 2 (it's seems correct), there are 2 frames. for second alert return is [object DOMWindow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i figure what was the problem. I try the code from above on Google Chrome on a system local file. Due the security settings of Google Chrome this usecase is impossible. If i move all files on a web server this will work as a charm
Thanks all for your support, this thread can be closed now

Comment: You are responsible for closing the thread by marking an answer (your own or someone elses) as answered.

Comment: ok, i will accept this answer tomorrow ... as the suggestion on the tooltip

Answer (score 3):

Use `contentWindow.document` instead of `document`:

```
var frame = window.parent.frames[0].contentWindow;
alert(frame.document.getElementById('textToSearch').value);
```

You can also just use `contentDocument` for most browsers, but not Internet Explorer 7 or older.

- [*contentWindow* - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533692(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answer ... but didn't work. i receive Cannot read property 'document' of undefined. If i want to see what is in variable 'frame' with alert, i have 'undefined'

Comment: @tinti: that's strange.  There's no *document* property for an iframe element in Chrome, but there are *contentWindow* and *contentDocument* properties.  If it's finding the frame, the code I gave you **should** work.

Comment: I don't know if is a problem, but i use frame instead of iframe. <frameset cols="20%,*">
      <frame name="frame1" id="frame1" src="f1.html"/>
      <frame name="frame2" id="frame2" src="f2.html"/>
   </frameset>

Comment: @tinti: I meant frame element (force of habit).  The properties are very similar. *contentDocument* is defined in the DOM level 2 spec, but all current browsers implement *contentWindow*.

Comment: Ok, but after your first line i insert alert(frame). It's 'undefined' ... so the second line is senseless. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: You have other advice for me?

Comment: @tinti: I'm afraid not, I don't see what else could be the problem.