# document.getElementById("abc").scroll not working for Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on angularjs. I have a div which has independent scroll. I am trying to make it scroll to the bottom of the page using this line.

```
document.getElementById("abc").scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById("integrationId")));
```

I works fine for Mozilla Firefox but not for Chrome/Safari. On Chrome it gives undefined. 
If I use

```
window.scroll(0, findPos(document.getElementById("integrationId")));
```

Then it applies everywhere.

If I can avoid jquery, even better.

Comment: Please look into this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803719/getelementbyid-problem-in-google-chrome

Comment: Try this module https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll. You should always do this kind of manipulation in directives

Comment: You should use `scrollTo` or `scrollBy` when using plain javascript

Comment: I tried using scrollTo & scrollBy. But it is giving me the following error. TypeError: document.getElementById(...).scrollBy is not a function